# Modify the Amazon affiliate ID for a link in an AMP page

Tags: amp-html, flipboard

In order to better understand how Flipboard traffic performs compared to normal web traffic, we'd like to use a unique Amazon affiliate ID for Flipboard when they load our AMP page in their mobile app.

AMP offers [amp-script](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-script/) for custom JavaScript, but it has significant limitations. Notably, it doesn't let you mutate the DOM without associated user input. The best idea I've come to is:

```
<script id="entry-content" type="text/plain" target="amp-script">
    document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(function(el) {
        el.addEventListener('click', function() {
            var link = el.getAttribute('href');
            if (-1 === link.indexOf('amazon.com')) {
                return;
            }
            el.setAttribute('href', link.replace(/tag=[A-Za-z0-9\-]+/, 'tag=newid' ));
        });
    });
</script>
```

AMP allows the mutation but the browser uses the original `link` value for the new tab, so that doesn't work.

I've also tried:

- Calling `window.open()` in the `click` event handler. `open()` isn't available though.
- Simply modifying the links on `document.addEventListener('scroll')`. AMP killed the mutations.

Any other crafty ideas?

Comment: Can you adapt to this approach: https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-link-rewriter/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @JayGray! That _almost_ looks like it would do the trick, except for one gotcha: it doesn't appear I can inspect the User Agent when the JSON blob is generated.

Comment: I fear that there is no front-end solution for this since you will not be allowed to modify the DOM without interaction. One solution that I can think of, is doing the User Agent check in the back-end and simply render the link "properly" from the get go.